# Java 8 Collectors.averagingLong trying to cast Double to long?

Tags: java

I have function like bellow that should calculate average `lastModified` of all files that share some specified name (they are in different directories).

```
private static long getAverageTimestamp(List<File> files, String filter) {

    return files.stream()
                .filter(f -> f.getName().equals(filter))
                .collect(Collectors.averagingLong(File::lastModified));

}
```

The issue is that `Collectors.averagingLong` is complaining that it cannot cast `Double` to `long`.

Where is this double coming from since `File::lastModified` returns `long` ?

From the javadoc of `lastModified`:

> Returns:A **long** value representing the time the file was last modified, measured in milliseconds since the epoch (00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970)...

Comment: The average of long numbers is not necessarily a long (think of the average of 1 and 2 for example)... averagingLong [returns a double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-)

Comment: what is the point of having both averagingLong and averagingDouble then? I would expect long variant to throw away decimal points O_O

Comment: One averages longs and the other averages doubles (as a source of data) but both return a double. You can cast that double to a long if you don't need the decimal part...

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I still think that name is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of the `getAverageTimestamp` is long. Yet the return type of stream operation is double because `averagingLong` collects to doubles. Hence you get the error about being unable to cast from double to long. See [Java 8 Documentation on Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-).

To be exact, the signature of `averagingLong` is:

```
<T> Collector<T,?,Double> averagingLong(ToLongFunction<? super T> mapper)
```

The method returns a `Collector<T,?,Double>`. This gets plugged into the collect function which has the signature.

```
<R,A> R collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)
```

In this signature R is the generic return type of the collect call and matches the third parameter of the collectors type. This is a double for the collector returned by `averagingLong` so the return type of `collect` becomes double.